# Meaning of "Yaa" in Rudram first Anuvaka, second verse

Tags: sanskrit, yajur-veda, rudram

This the second verse of Sri Rudram

> **yAta ishus**-shivatama shivam babhUva te dhanuH /
> shivA sharavyA yA  tava tayA no rudra mRRiDaya //

The first word in the first line can be divided into या | ते | इषुः =या त इषुः. I want to know the meaning of या. Especially since it also seems to be repeated in next few verses.

Or is my Sandhi Vichhedh wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well in general when you are referring to the Supreme Lord/Devi you use the word "Ya" as in the verse stated above and others out there in Sri Rudram for instance:

> **या तेरुद्र** शिवा तनू-रघोराऽपापकाशिनी ।
>
> तया नस्तनुवा शन्तमया गिरिशंताभिचाकशीहि ॥ १-३
>
> **Ya te Rudra** Shiva tanura ghora papakashini
>
> taya nastanuva shantamaya girishanta bhichakashihi
>
> **O Lord Rudra**, One with terrible form, destroyer of sins
>
> With your peaceful, auspeciousness bless us.

Or this one:

> **यामिषुं** गिरिशंत हस्ते बिभर्ष्यस्तवे।
>
> शिवां गिरित्र तां कुरु मा हिसीः पुरुषं जगत् ॥ १-४
>
> **Yamishum** giri shanta haste bibharsya stave
>
> shivam giritra tam Kuru ma higmsih purusham jagat
>
> **O Lord living in the Mountains**, giver of good things.
>
> Make us peaceful, let the material world exist

Also as in Devi Suktam:

> **या देवी** सर्वभुतेषु **Ya Devi** Sarvabhutesu
> means  **O Devi** of all souls, creatures

In other words it's part of the salutation. The consonant य् (y) with अ (a) added to it merely for the sake of facility in pronunciation